# GnuRadio logger append file flag not working?

Tags: python, gnuradio

I am trying to log some information generated during the running of a flowgraph to a log file.  I am using the following commands:

```
    log = gr.logger('log')
    log.set_level("DEBUG")
    log_filename = config_prms['logging']['log_filename']  #full path to log file
    log.add_file_appender(log_filename, False, "%r :%p: %c{1} - %m%n")
```

where the second argument, to the best of my understanding, determines whether the log file is to be overwritten or appended to (https://www.gnuradio.org/doc/doxygen/classgr_1_1logger.html#a59623c0e5e128b2d86c59b93240ba034).  It turns out that the log file is always appended to (irrespective of whether that flag is True or False).  Is this expected behavior?

Answer (score 0):

No, that's a bug. Please report it in full, including your GNU Radio version, under https://github.com/gnuradio/gnuradio/issues .